# Get previous emitted items after flatMap to empty Observable

Tags: rx-java

I want to fill each `Company` with its `Employee`s and then save it in persistent storage, so I have this code:

```
public Observable<Company> getCompanies() {
    return repository.getCompanies()
             .flatMap(new Func1<Company, Observable<Employee>>() {
                 @Override
                 public Observable<Employee> call(Company company) {
                     if (company.hasEmployees()) {
                        return repository.getEmployees(company);
                     } else {
                        return Observable.empty();
                     }
                 }
             }, new Func2<Company, Employee, Company>() {
                 @Override
                 public Company call(Company company, Employee employee) {
                     company.addEmployee(employee);
                     return company;
                 }
             }).doOnNext(save());
}

private Action1<Company> save() {
    //more code...
}
```

As you see, not all companies have employees, so `Observable.empty()` is returned in some cases. That causes that `save()` is not called and not all the `Company`s are persisted.

How can I solve this? I want to store all the companies, not only those that have any employee. The `save()` method has to be called after fill the company with the employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Now, if Company has no employees, `Observable.just(Collections.emptyList())` is returned, instead of `Observable.empty()`. Any comment will be appreciated